# Phpstorm 9 ssh session Auth Cancel

Tags: ssh, vagrant, phpstorm

I'm trying to start a SSH Session on a Vagrant machine but I have an Auth cancel error.
How to solve?

Comment: more info required. Some code for example?

Comment: I'm trying to ssh into a Vagrant box with Mac OSX and Windows 10. It works perfectly from the Terminal, but when I use PHPStorm's native "Tools -> Start SSH session..." I have the error.

Comment: it would be great if you would tell us what error ...

Comment: not sure how phpstorm behaves; can you access the vm from the cli using ssh command ?

Comment: The error is:
**Connecting to 127.0.0.1:2222**
**Auth Cancel**
I have this error on Mac and on Windows.
I can access the VM with terminal.

Comment: Likely because vagrant has its own private/public key. Unless you're telling PHPStorm to use this, it wont be able to ssh into it. More information would be helpful, the question is very vague and shows no attempts at previous troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this error also. The problem was caused by the fact that have I many vagrant machines across multiple projects. For each Vagrant machine I have a PHP interpreter defined in the PHPStorm settings. My project was configured to use one vagrant machine, but use the PHP interpreter from another vagrant machine. By going into Settings→Languages & Frameworks→PHP and then selecting the correct interpreter.

I know this question is quite old, but it was the top Google result when searching for this problem, so hopefully this will help someone else.